# WooCommerce REST API create product in batch with meta_data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-rest-api

```
  $data = array
    (
        [0] => array
            (
                [name] => Mark
                [published] => 0
                [sku] => mark
                [regular_price] => 12
                [meta_data] => array
                    (
                        [0] => array
                            (
                                [key] => API
                                [value] => using REST
                            )

                        [1] => array
                            (
                                [key] => Test M
                                [value] => TST
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => array
            (
                [name] => Mark – II
                [published] => 0
                [sku] => Mark-ii
                [regular_price] => 4
                [meta_data] => array
                    (
                        [0] => array
                            (
                                [key] => API
                                [value] => using REST ii
                            )

                        [1] => array
                            (
                                [key] => Test M
                                [value] => TST ii
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

print_r( $store_client->post( 'products/batch', ['create' => $data ] ) );
```

I tried to create batch products with metadata, but it fails. If metadata is not there, it's working fine. Any issues with the array of meta.?

[Documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product) not saying any details.

Comment: show me your code.